# Is c++ floating point calculation consistent in android and iOS?

Tags: android, c++, ios, floating-point, java-native-interface

for example, if I have a c++ function has so many floating point operations (e.g.:division,sqrt,sin,cos...) but have no rand(), can I ensure it would get same result in both android and iOS?

for example, will a function findValue(123.456) return 3.52111 in android but return 3.52205 in iOS?

Answer (score 2):

They don't have to be consistent at all since C++ does not mandate a particular floating point type.

(Although, more often than not a floating point double will be an IEEE754 type: the one insisted upon by Java.)

If you include the line

`static_assert(std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559, "Not IEEE754");`

in your source code, then compilation will fail if the floating point is not the one you expect. In the absence of the assertion, you can be confident that the arithmetic operations will be extremely similar.

Comment: IIRC actual real IEEE754 is fairly rare. The IEEE754 _format_ is ubiquitous, though.

Answer (score 0):

No. Even if you have a fully compliant IEEE754 `double`, that just guarantees that +-/* and `sqrt` are correct to the last bit. `sin` and `cos` usually have errors, although those will still be fairly small for `sin(123.456)`. But it would be a surprise if `sin(123456.789)` was correct.